# remote connection to mysql from tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

sorry my english. My mysql server and tomcat server are running localhost, And my gwt web application is running correctly on Localhost, Then my web application connected mysql database. 
Then I deployed my web application (.war file) to another tomcat server(linux),  it cannot connect to mysql (windows server) server. why?

Answer (score 0):

In your tomcat configuration file, you specified "localhost" as your database server. Change that to the hostname of the MySQL server.